# Can a upvote increase the visibility of a question?

Tags: discussion

I was curious to know that upvoting the question (Not answer) will that increase the visibility of the question so that many people will come to answer it or it will only show the poster that your question will be helpful to other in future.

And is that a good idea to upvote the old questions that are inactive for a long time but that hacks still works?

Comment: Upvoting a question is meant to be done when it's a well-researched question where the user has shown effort in fixing the issue or investigating the question themselves beforehand - not because a question hasn't been answered.

Comment: _is that a good idea to upvote the old questions that are inactive for a long time_ It won't work as expected. there are certain actions that bump the question to homepage like answering and editing. Voting vote do that

Answer (score 1):

Upvoting doesn't directly increase visibility in the sense of bumping it to the top of the list, but I do think it changes how people interact with a question and even how many people will see it indirectly, moreso in the early life of a question.

For example, it is possible to use advanced search options to filter questions by score. e.g. `score:1` limits you to questions with a score of one or more. I don't know how many people use this search filter, but obviously upvoting a question makes it more likely it won't get filtered out.

Also, some people do not like answering downvoted questions and are more likely to consider answering a question which has already gained positive attention from the rest of the community. A question scored 2 is more likely to encourage people to click through and read it in full than a question scored -2.

On very old questions, however, an upvote is unlikely to do anything other than give more reputation to the person who asked it originally.